# Magento onestep checkout page Gives error

Tags: magento

I am using one step checkout extention  in magento.here i am adding 2 custom shipping method in (Standard Shipping and  Next Day Delivery).when I am selecting it every time it gives errors ("ReferenceError: lastPrice is not defined").[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnIaI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this is by enabling display error using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and debug the error.